# calculate remaining height using CSS calc()

Tags: css

I need the `.content` div use all the available space

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.nav {
    padding: 20px;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
}

<body>
    <div class="nav">nav</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</body>
```

Since I don't know the height of the `.nav` I can't use `height: calc(100%-Xpx)`
is there any other way to make `.content` use the remaining height of the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `min-height: 100vh` on `body`, then set the parent (`body` in this case) to `display: flex; flex-direction: column` and use `flex-grow: 1` on `.content` for it to use the available space.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav {
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">nav</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```